# nvidia-settings without nvidia dedicated X Server

Tags: linux, xorg, nvidia, gpu

I have a machine that I'm using the on board video card  (non-nvidia) to drive the monitor, and I have 2 Nvidia GPU's installed and functional with the latest drivers. My CUDA GPU applications work but I'd like to tweak some settings. From my understanding, nvidia-settings can't be used unless an nvidia GPU is driving a monitor (real or virtual), is this correct?

I'm really looking for a solution for tweaking GPU settings without having to have an Nvidia GPU driving a monitor, or X at all. I simply don't want CUDA resources being used at all to drive a monitor. 
Maybe running nvidia-settings on Xvfb or something similar is an option?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `nvidia-settings` uses a proprietary API to talk to the proprietary `nvidia` driver, and the driver itself will execute the modifications. There's no way of using `nvidia-settings` without the `nvidia` X driver running, which implies that X is running.

It may be possible to run the `nvidia` X driver without actually having it drive any output by tweaking the `xorg.conf` file.

You didn't explain *why* you don't want the X and the driver running. If the reason is that you don't need them and only want to run the CUDA applications headless without a monitor connected, then it won't hurt if you run both, and don't use any X applications, and disable the output or put it into powersavings mode. That way, no resources will be used. If there's another reason, please edit the question and explain.

**Edit**

CUDA resources **aren't** used to drive a monitor. The card consists of a number of GPU cores, RAM, a number of "heads" that treat the RAM as framebuffer and convert it into various video signals, and lots of diverse logic. When the monitor is active, the "head" part reads out the framebuffer and displays it. That doesn't use any GPU cores at all, these are only used to *produce* an image in the framebuffer if the card does rendering using OpenGL etc. The only drawback of having the "head" active is that it takes power, and that it needs to access the RAM, which may or may not slow down GPU RAM access somewhat depending on how the RAM is organized and how the RAM is used. But of the "head" is in DPMS power saving state, even the framebuffer is not accessed, so there's **no** resource usage at all.

And the same happens when you use a framebuffer driver - X is really a framebuffer driver with an ancient interface (the framebuffer interface is a lot simpler), and OpenGL thrown on top of the ancient protocol.

So, there's no need to worry.

Comment: I have updated the original post.

Comment: I have more reasons to do what I'm looking for. But rather than focus on my reasons. Lets focus on the question. 

I really need to keep the integrated graphics as the primary video out. If a second X server needs to be running so nvidia settings will work, then thats ok. 
I'm thinking I would be able to start s second X session and have nvidia-settings run on it.